# How to optimise an Image in React Native and view on latest iPhone models

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

Photos captured via camera are too large for efficient upload and download in React native. Also i am facing issues in displaying images in latest iPhone models like X, XS, XSMax and XR

I am using the npm package *react-native-image-picker*. Though it works well but i cannot resize the image which is the main concern for me!!

The result expected: I should be able to resize the image and upload it to server as well as view it in all mobile phones.

The actual result: I cannot resize the image and also cannot view the image on iPhone X and other latest iPhone models.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [expo-image-manipulator](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-image-manipulator) to compress images.

If you use expo it is pre installed and you can import it directly:

```
import { ImageManipulator } from 'expo';

const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
    image,
    [],
    { compress: 0.5 }
);
```

Otherwise you must install it as a standalone package and use it like this:

```
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';

const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
    image,
    [],
    { compress: 0.5 }
);
```

compress must be value in range 0.0 - 1.0 specifying compression level of the result image. 1 means no compression (highest quality) and 0 the highest compression (lowest quality).

For more info see the [Image Manipulator docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/imagemanipulator/)

Comment: What about images in iPhone latest phones?